# Стих и стихи

Tags: грамотная-речь

Когда речь идет об одном стихотворении, правильно ли употреблять слово "стих"? Стих может быть в Библии, но в данном случае я спрашиваю об обычных стихах. Или все-таки надо говорить "стихи" или "стихотворение", а слово "стих" несет несколько пренебрежительный оттенок?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово СТИХ в одном из своих значений - единица ритмически организованной поэтической речи, *строка поэтического произведения*. Если же речь идет о стихотворном произведении, то лучше говорить **стихотворение** (небольшое поэтическое произведение, написанное ритмизованной речью, стихами). Употребление слова **стих** в значении 'небольшое поэтическое произведение' является разговорным.

Comment: Тихотворение мое, мое немое,
однако, тяглое - на страх поводьям,
куда пожалуемся на ярмо и
кому поведаем, как жизнь проводим?
Как поздно заполночь ища глазунию
луны за шторою зажженной спичкою,
вручную стряхиваешь пыль безумия
с осколков желтого оскала в писчую.
Как эту борзопись, что гуще патоки,
там не размазывай, но с кем в колене и
в локте хотя бы преломить, опять-таки,
ломоть отрезанный, тихотворение? 

И. Бродский